How to set past_covariates in darts library correctly ? - ValueError - The past_covariates are not long enough
I am trying to do time series forecasting in darts library and I want to predict output variable based on 2 inputs - i1 and i2.
I want to use last 7 day values of i1 and i2 to predict output variable. I want to predict for next 90 days (horizon = 90)
Just to set things up, I tried creating dummy data and set up the code as below -
Data Set up
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set the start and end date
start_date = '2021-09-01'
end_date = '2024-06-30'

# Create a date range
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

# Generate random data for i1, i2, and output columns within specified ranges
np.random.seed(42)  # For reproducibility
i1 = np.random.uniform(0, 100, len(date_range))
i2 = np.random.uniform(1, 10, len(date_range))
output = np.random.uniform(1000, 5000, len(date_range))

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ds': date_range,
    'i1': i1,
    'i2': i2,
    'output': output
})

# Display the first few rows of the DataFrame
print(df.head())

# Plot the time series data
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))
plt.plot(df['ds'], df['i1'], label='i1 (0-100)')
plt.plot(df['ds'], df['i2'], label='i2 (1-10)')
plt.plot(df['ds'], df['output'], label='output (1000-5000)')

# Customize the plot
plt.title('Time Series Data')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()



Below is the code to perform time series forecasting using RegressionModel that accepts past covariates
from darts import TimeSeries
from darts.models import LinearRegressionModel
from darts.metrics import mape
from darts.utils.missing_values import fill_missing_values
from darts.dataprocessing.transformers import Scaler


# Initialize scalers and scale the data
scaler_output = Scaler()
scaler_covariates = Scaler()

series_output = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df, 'ds', 'output')
series_covariates = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df, 'ds', ['i1', 'i2'])

# Fill missing values and scale
series_output = fill_missing_values(series_output)
series_covariates = fill_missing_values(series_covariates)

series_output = scaler_output.fit_transform(series_output)
series_covariates = scaler_covariates.fit_transform(series_covariates)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
train_output = series_output[:-90]
test_output = series_output[-90:]

# When splitting covariates, ensure they start early enough
train_covariates = series_covariates[:-90]
test_covariates = series_covariates[-90:]

# Initialize and train the model
# Increase the lags to ensure coverage
model = LinearRegressionModel(lags=None, lags_past_covariates=[-7])
model.fit(train_output, past_covariates=train_covariates)

# Predict the next 90 days using "test_covariates"
pred_covariates = model.predict(90, past_covariates=test_covariates)

# Inverse scale the predictions for interpretability
pred_covariates = scaler_output.inverse_transform(pred_covariates)
test_output = scaler_output.inverse_transform(test_output)

# Compare with actual values using MAPE
mape_covariates = mape(test_output, pred_covariates)
print(f'MAPE with covariates: {mape_covariates}')

The code pred_covariates = model.predict(90, past_covariates=test_covariates) gives below error -
ValueError: The `past_covariates` are not long enough. 
Given horizon `n=90`, `min(lags_past_covariates)=-7`, `max(lags_past_covariates)=-7` and `output_chunk_length=90`, the `past_covariates` have to range from 2024-03-26 00:00:00 until 2024-03-26 00:00:00 (inclusive), but they only range from 2024-04-02 00:00:00 until 2024-06-30 00:00:00.

I am new to time series forecasting and I am not able to fully comprehend so as to why this error arises even though I have correctly split the data into train and test for output and covariates too.
